# Cannot convert from Spanish date string to LocalDate in Java

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, setlocale, datetimeformatter

Hello I'm here for a DateTimeFormatter problem with the Locale formatter language, let me introduce you:

- I'm reading a CSV file with this String Format: "dd-MMM-yyyy" <--> "28-dic-2017"
- Then I have to parse each string from a list to LocalDate to handle each with timeAPI methods.
- Notice that I have my months in spanish abrev. that's the mess!!
- When Executed it returns:

Observed error with stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '28-dic-2017' could not be parsed at index 3
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
    at com.examen.Presentation.Principal.parseDate(Principal.java:28)
    at com.examen.Presentation.Principal.main(Principal.java:19)
```

Minimal, reproducible code example:

```
public static LocalDate parseDate(String fecha) {

    Locale loc = new Locale("es", "ES");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", loc);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(fecha, formatter);

    return date;
}
```

I've got the same error trying different things and methods from locale and DateTimeFormatter don't even know what i was doing, but I think that this should work OBVIOUSLY NOT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the other answer geocodezip has already explained why your attempt failed. Here are two suggestions for solutions that I find more elegant than the one in that answer.

### Java locale data providers

Java can get its locale data including month abbreviations in different languages from up to four sources. Since Java 9 by default it prefers to get them from CLDR, the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository. In CLDR Spanish month abbreviations are with a dot (or *full point*) as explained in the other answer, like `dic.` for *diciembre*. Another source is the locale data that were built-in with Java since the early versions (and were the default until Java 8). Here Spanish month abbreviations haven’t got dots (and your data may have been produced by a program running on Java 8 or earlier, I cannot know). These locale data are referred to as `COMPAT` for compatible with earlier Java versions. When you launch your program, you can specify on the command line that Java should prefer COMPAT over CLDR, for example:

```
java -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR YourJavaMainClass
```

This will cause your existing code to accept `dic` and other month abbreviations without dot.

It’s a global setting for the JVM, so it will also cause any locale-sensitive operation anywhere in your program and in other programs running in the same JVM to use the old locale data from Java 8. Think twice.

### DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendText()

Since you know that your format is always `28-dic-2017`, you may also make yourself completely independent of any locale data simply by specifying explicitly which month abbreviations are used in your input data.

```
private static Map<Long, String> getMonthAbbreviations() {
    return Map.ofEntries(
            Map.entry(1L, "ene"),
            Map.entry(2L, "feb"),
            Map.entry(3L, "mar"),
            Map.entry(4L, "abr"),
            Map.entry(5L, "may"),
            Map.entry(6L, "jun"),
            Map.entry(7L, "jul"),
            Map.entry(8L, "ago"),
            Map.entry(9L, "sep"),
            Map.entry(10L, "oct"),
            Map.entry(11L, "nov"),
            Map.entry(12L, "dic"));
}

private static final DateTimeFormatter inputDateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("dd-")
        .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, getMonthAbbreviations())
        .appendPattern("-uuuu")
        .toFormatter();
```

This formatter is independent of locale and parses your date string:

```
    String fecha = "28-dic-2017";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(fecha, inputDateFormatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output is:

> 2017-12-28

### A tip for parsing problems: try formatting first

A tip: when parsing doesn’t work, you may try formatting first to get to know how the string to be parsed was supposed to look like and compare to the string that you were trying to parse. For example:

```
    Locale loc = new Locale("es", "ES");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", loc);
    
    System.out.println("Want to parse: 28-dic-2017");
    System.out.println("Formatted:     "
            + LocalDate.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 28).format(formatter));
    System.out.println("Want to parse: 29-sep-2017");
    System.out.println("Formatted:     "
            + LocalDate.of(2017, Month.SEPTEMBER, 29).format(formatter));
```

> ```
> Want to parse: 28-dic-2017
> Formatted:     28-dic.-2017
> Want to parse: 29-sep-2017
> Formatted:     29-sept.-2017
> ```

Now we can at least see what is wrong for a start.

### Documentation links

- [`LocaleServiceProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html) listing the possible sources of locale data in Java
- [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendText(TemporalField, Map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendText(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,java.util.Map))

Comment: In love with your mind!! you've solved it!! Thank you for your time voted and accepted as solution + thank's for the comment on my post!!

Comment: in addition to your Response i've noticed that Map.ofEntries is Java9 like and i cannot make use of it, I've already solved id using new HashMap<>() instead

Comment: I’m a bit surprised to read that you’re using Java 8, not 9. Your code from the question works on (my) Java 8 for `28-dic-2017` (but fails on Java 11 with the exception you mentioned). In any case, the only important thing is that you have found a solution.

Answer (score 4):

For Spanish, the `DateTimeFormatter` expects the abbreviated month to be terminated with a period.  Like this:  `28-dic.-2017`

If *all* your dates are in that format, you can parse the input string to add the period, then send it to the `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
public static LocalDate parseDate(String fecha) {
    int firstDash = fecha.indexOf('-')+1;
    int secondDash = fecha.indexOf('-', fecha.indexOf('-')+1);
    String month = fecha.substring(firstDash, secondDash);
    String dateStr = fecha.substring(0,firstDash)+month+"."+fecha.substring(secondDash);
    Locale loc = new Locale("es", "ES");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", loc);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter);

    return date;
}
```

If the format sometimes has the period, you would need to add it if it isn't already there:

```
public static LocalDate parseDate(String fecha) {
    String dateStr;
    if (fecha.indexOf(".")!=-1) {
        dateStr = fecha;
    } else {
        int firstDash = fecha.indexOf('-')+1;
        int secondDash = fecha.indexOf('-', fecha.indexOf('-')+1);
        String month = fecha.substring(firstDash, secondDash);
        dateStr = fecha.substring(0,firstDash)+month+"."+fecha.substring(secondDash);
    }
    System.out.println(dateStr);
    Locale loc = new Locale("es", "ES");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", loc);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter);

    return date;
}
```

**output:**

> 2017-12-28

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!! I've tested your solution first but as Ole V.V. said I'm using Java 8 and i got the same problem + it returns "29-dic.-2017"; your code adds 1 to the day (cause i have no 29-dic-2017 anyway it's been a pleasure to see what can be done, i'm newbie to Java

Comment: *it returns "29-dic.-2017"; your code adds 1 to the day* Are you sure? I can’t see how that can happen, and I also cannot reproduce it.

Comment: ok my mess, it works fine till 29-sep-2017 i was to fast reading this..
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '29-sep.-2017' could not be parsed at index 3
 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2051)
 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1953)
 at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:429)
 at com.examen.Presentation.Principal.parseDate(Principal.java:41)
 at com.examen.Presentation.Principal.main(Principal.java:28)
.

Comment: That’s another difference between COMPAT and CLDR locale data! @implor COMPAT has `sep` (as I suppose your CSV file has),. CLDR has `sept.` with a `t` and a dot. So cannot parse `sep.` without `t` even though the dot has been edited in.

Comment: This might be the mistake, anyway it's solved in your code implementation WITHOUT -> java -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR YourJavaMainClass