# How to convert date from this format "dd/MMM/yyyy" to any other format with Java 17 version?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, java-17

I am  trying to convert date from this format "dd/MMM/yyyy" to "yyyyMMdd",
for Java 1.8 version ,the code was working fine, my code is

```
       SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormat);
       SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(newFormat);
       Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateStr);
       return outputFormat.format(date);
```

when i changed from Java 8 to java 17 , I am getting parse Exception. Please help, thanks

Comment: Note that the classes ur using there are all outdated. Prefer using the stuff from `java.time` instead.

Comment: What input are you using?

Comment: Which is your default locale? Is it the same in your Java 17 installation as in your Java 8 installation? Also please at least post the full message from the exception.

Comment: Java’s locale data — including the abbreviations for months in different languages — changed a lot from Java 8 to Java 9 and have had further changes since. This is a probable explanation for your error, but without more details and a [mre] we can’t tell whether it is the reason. See more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244724/jdk-dateformater-parsing-dayofweek-in-german-locale-java8-vs-java9) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394366/cannot-convert-from-spanish-date-string-to-localdate-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

For j**vm17** do use `java.time.*` instead.

```java
public static String convert(String dateStr) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH));
    return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE, Locale.ENGLISH);
}
```

And the client's code will look like this:

```java
String dateStr = "22/Jul/2023";
System.out.println(convert(dateStr));   // 20230722
```

Comment: I think the unspecified locale cannot deal with MMM.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is a backward compatible requirement you should avoid the old Date classes and their supporting classes.  They are buggy and obsolete.

From the `java.time` package.

What you want is the BASIC_ISO_DATE which is predefined.  So all that is required is the `from` format.  Add locales as appropriate for your requirements.

```
String dateString = "10/Jan/2023";
 
DateTimeFormatter from = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate ldt = LocalDate.parse(dateString, from);
String result = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
20230110
```

Check out the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package for a rich set of classes to manipulate various dates and times.